# Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть лист

```
result1 = ['"United States"', '"China"', '"Sweden"', '"Europe"', '"Russian Federation"', '"China"']
```

я его хочу вставить в дб

```
con.execute("INSERT INTO TableName(contry) VALUES(?)", result1)
```

но выдает ошибку:

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1,
>   and there are 74 supplied.

Comment: как ваши обстоят дела в борьбе с ошибкой?

Answer (score 1):

Запятую после последнего элемента списка поставьте.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Получил из `['"United States"', '"China"'..]` такой список `[ [ "United States", ["China"], .... ]` и ошибка исчезла